# Two similar rspec tests, giving opposite results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have a user model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email, :name
  # admin only
  attr_accessible :email, :name, :admin, :as => :admin
```

And the following model spec:

```
describe "accessible attributes" do

  let(:new_user){ FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
  @admin_attrs = { admin: true, name: "ben", email: "xyz@test.com"}

  it "can not be set on create" do

    # variant 1 - test fails, AM::MAS::Error NOT thrown
    expect do
      User.new(@admin_attrs)
    end.should raise_error(ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error)

    # variant 2 - test passes, AM::MAS::Error NOT thrown
    expect do
      User.new(admin: true, name: "ben", email: "xyz@test.com", password: "123xyz", password_confirmation: "123xyz")
    end.should raise_error(ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error)

  end
```

I can't figure out why variant 1 of my test fails, but variants 2 passes. The error message I get is:

```
1) User accessible attributes can not be set on create
     Failure/Error: expect do
       expected ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error but nothing was raised
```

They are basically the same test. What am I doing wrong? In fact, if I perform test 1 from the console, it does throw a MAS::Error, as expected. I'm confused.

Comment: Why did you write `let(:new_user){ FactoryGirl.create(:user) }` and never user `new_user` method? If you need an admin, you can pass `admin: true` in `FactoryGirl.create` or even create separate factory for admins by extending `user`'s factory (see `parent` key in docs https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#inheritance).

Comment: @jdoe, thanks, I do use the `new_user` object, just elsewhere, thanks for the link

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@admin_attrs is probably nil as far as your first text example is concerned because it's not being set up in a before hook (or through 'let')

Comment: This is correct. To clarify - `describe` generates a class and `it` generates (effectively) an instance method. `@admin_attrs` is declared at the class level and is not available to the instance method.

Comment: Thanks both of you, this makes sense to me now.